# Issue when creating a new Recurring Donation through Salesforce API

Tags: php, api, salesforce

Recently I have hit an error as described below:

Error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY 
Message: npe03.RecurringDonations: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.NullPointerException: Argument 1 cannot be null (npe03)

I'm writing in PHP, and this is what my array looks like:

```
$newRecurring = array();
$newRecurring['Name'] = "Recurring: {$recurring['id']}";
$newRecurring['npe03__Amount__c'] = $recurring['amount'];
$newRecurring['npe03__Date_Established__c'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($recurring['date']));
$newRecurring['npe03__Installment_Period__c'] = 'Monthly';
$newRecurring['npe03__Organization__c'] = $account; //I double checked, it is a valid Id
```

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: There's Stack Exchange another site dedicated to Salesforce, where this question might get more attention: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Comment: And [this may be helpful](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/caused-by-System-NullPointerException-Attempt-to-de-reference-a/m-p/472651#M86661)

Comment: Thanks a lot ~ question posted there ~